# PHP ZipArchive class does not create archive

Tags: php, zip, cakephp-3.0, php-ziparchive

I am trying to create an archive of selected files using following code

```
$zip_in = new \ZipArchive;
if ($zip_in->open('input.zip') === TRUE) {
    $files = array();
    for ($loop = 0; $loop < $zip_in->numFiles; $loop++) {
        $files[] = $zip_in->getNameIndex($loop);
    }
    $zip_in->extractTo('workspace');
    $zip_in->close();
    /**
     * Changes done to files extracted inside WORKSPACE DIR above
     */
    chdir('workspace');
    $zip_out = new \ZipArchive();
    $zip_out->open('output.zip', \ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $zip_out->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip_out->close();
}
```

Here I am trying to extract **input.zip** archive to **workspace** directory to make changes in files contained inside the zip archive. Following this, I want to again zip all the files back into **output.zip** archive.

The variable `$files` used to store extracted file names is not touched anywhere while editing the files. The file names are hardcoded and not received via any variable.

The last line to finally save the **output.zip** archive gives following warning on the console:

> PHP Warning:   ZipArchive::close(): Read error: Is a directory in /home/user/zip.php on line 100

I am unable to understand the reason for this failure. The error message is unclear. What is the reason for this failure ?

**Edit:**

As requested, added the code to call the archive handler discussed above.

```
class A {
    public function A1 () {
        /**
         * the code above
         */
    }
}

class B {
    public function B1 {
        $a = new A();
        $a->A1();
    }
}
```

This is part of CakePHP 3 app. Taking the hint comments, when I run the code independently outside of CakePHP 3 app it works just fine. However inside the CakePHP app there is some problem. I am adding additional tags to highlight the question in CakePHP community.

Answer (score 1):

Because your code is wrong and you are replacing the instance of ZipArchive by a file:

$zip = addFile($file);

replace with :

$zip->addFile($file);

Comment: No, it was a typo here on stackoverflow not in actual code. I am making that correction. Thanks for pointing it out !

Comment: Can you give me the code for $files and be sure that in this files there are only files and not a directory ?

Comment: Thanks for taking interest in the question. I have added the required details in the question above.

Comment: Your code is working for me. How do you launch the php script ?

Comment: Thanks for the effort in running the code locally.

I run the code this way:
    `class A {
        public function A1 () {
            /**
             * the code above
             */
        }
    }

    class B {
        public function B1 {
            $a = new A();
            $a->A1();
        }
    }`

This whole stuff is inside CakePHP 3 app

Comment: Oh! this looks bad I will add it up there